# Is "It's better I go to your place" a proper grammatical usage of "Had better"?

Tags: grammar

I was unable to find anything on the "It is better/best + pronoun +verb" on the Internet. Could it be because it is not used?

My question is: what follows the pronoun in the "It's better/best + pronoun" construct.

It's better (if I?) I went to your place. 
It's better I go to your place.

I would me more than thankful if someone could point me towards a source explaining this or if they could explain it to me. Thank you.

Comment: _It would be better if I went to your place._ // _It is better if I go to your place._

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with the colloquial superlative injunction *[It's] **best you don't**!*, for example, not including the word ***if***. The comparative, ***Better you don't**!* sounds slightly weird, but that's probably because it's less familiar (people would rarely have *reason* to use the "weaker" version; nothing to do with syntactic validity as such).

Comment: _I had better..._ is a shorter and more emphatic way of saying _It would be better if I..._ Your version _It is better if I..._ is much less common, because you are talking about something that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: As @Kate says, "I had better [do X]" conveys some urgency. "I'd better get on and do it. [Things will be bad if I don't.]" With emphasis on 'I', it means the speaker believes that the matter is too important / demanding to leave to someone else. //// "It's better/best [if] I [do X] more often (than the previous expression) means [I, rather than anyone else], but is more philosophical, rather than connoting a real sense of urgency. _Yes, it's the best thing to do, after due consideration._